# "Cannot read property" [JS]

Tags: javascript

There are, again, many problems and solutions but I cannot seem to find a answer to my question.

1. Goal: this is a lexer for my custom, garbage programming language.
2. Expected: advance function will change values
   Actual: it doesn't.
3. Error: cannot read property length of 'undefined'.

What I've tried:

bugfixing, changing the function code, looking it up.

! Edit: the error is on line 87. 
Code (a small snippet):

```
class Lexer {
    constructor(text) {
        this.text = text;
        this.pos = -1;
        this.current_char = 'None';
    }
    advance() {
        this.pos += 1;
        if (this.pos < this.text.length) { //this is line 87
            this.current_char = this.text[this.pos];
        } else {
            this.currenct_char = 'None';
        }
    }
```

Ask me if you need more code.

Comment: The problem is likely happening when the object is instantiated with undefined text. Check in the constructor.

Comment: thanks! I made a lexer with the text 'c' and ran advance. now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate your object, constructor param `text` is undefined, so `this.text` is undefined too.
You probably forgot param `text` or the variable send to constructor is undefined.

So when you call method `advance()`, it can't access property length on `this.text.length` because `this.text` is undefined.